# Job Results From LocalPrintServer GetPrintQueue Are In Wrong Order

Tags: c#, printing, .net-4.0, queue

I use the following routine to get my printer queue jobs.  For some reason they seem to be in the wrong order...

**Routine To Get List Of Printer Jobs:**

```
private List<string> GetPrinterQueueJobs(string targetPrinterName)
{
    List<string> jobs = new List<string>();

    string unc = null;
    string printerName = targetPrinterName;
    if (printerName.Contains("\\"))
    {
        string[] printerNameParts = printerName.Split('\\');
        unc = printerNameParts[0];
        printerName = printerNameParts[1];
    }

    PrintQueue printQue = null;
    if (unc == null)
    {
        //local printer
        printQue = new LocalPrintServer().GetPrintQueue(printerName);
    }
    else
    {
        //remote printer
        printQue = new PrintServer(unc).GetPrintQueue(printerName);
    }

    foreach (PrintSystemJobInfo queItem in printQue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection())
    {
        jobs.Insert(queItem.PositionInPrintQueue - 1, queItem.Name);
    }

    return jobs;
}
```

**Usage Of Routine:**

```
private void cbPrinters_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> printers = GetListOfPrinters();

    ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
    string printerName = cb.Text;

    if (printers.Contains(printerName))
    {
        List<string> printerQue = GetPrinterQueueJobs(printerName);
        foreach (string queItem in printerQue)
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(queItem);

            lvPrintQueue.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is what the Windows Print Queue looks like:**
[image: Windows Print Queue]

**This is what my results look like:**
[image: Returned Job Results]

As you can see in this case they are inverted.  The crazy thing is, when stepping through the routine I also check the "PositionInPrintQueue" property and it seems to think the jobs are actually in the order shown in my returned results.

Why is this happening?  Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get them to be returned in the correct order?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the Windows Printer Queue was not showing the items in order!  By default it does not show you the order of the jobs!  There is no type of "Queue Id", "Queue Index" or "Job Order" column in the Windows Printer Queue.  When looking at the jobs, you can sort by job name, status, owner, pages, size, port, and submitted.

If you sort by submitted they should all match the results returned in the `GetPrintJobInfoCollection()` method.  But in the end, don't trust the Windows Printer Queue for job order, trust the order returned in the `GetPrintJobInfoCollection()` method.